# How to use power of one when we have 2 level of grouping

Tags: reporting

I have two columns on custom objects, want to group by date first, then by user

Date    User

9 Sep   ABC

9 Sep   XYZ

10 Sep  ABC

10 Sep  XYZ

11 Sep  LMN

Need unique user count per day something like

Date        User Count

9 Sep        1

10 Sep       2

11 Sep       1

I know there is something power of one but not able to fit in my situation. Any Help.

Answer (score 1):

In reporting, first group by the `date__c` column. See https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_builder_fields_groupings.htm&language=en_US

Then, sort on on the `date__c` column as well. See https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_sorting.htm

Comment: This is just giving total count per user per day, I need number of unique users per day.